# Listing the functions in a KieBase

Tags: drools, business-rules, kie

I am uploading three drl files with three functions in each drl. Can I get the list that contains all the 9 functions that are loaded in my KieBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

From the `KieBase` you can get the list of `KiePackages` and for each of them you can get the name of the functions defined in them.

This simple code will list all the functions in a `KieBase`:

```
KieBase kbase = ...
List<String> functions = kbase.getKiePackages().stream()
    .flatMap(p -> p.getFunctionNames().stream())
    .collect(toList());
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: With this, I could get the function names, but is there any way where i can get the function along with its definition?.